Anyone Built an App Flow Custom Connector for youtube analytics api?
Having trouble with authentication with youtube analytics api. Seems as though I need to pass just the token json and make a refresh but the custom app flow connector is looking for a lot more. Any advice?
Tried Building the connector

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
